# Different structs implementing same interface in Golang

Tags: go

I have an interface

```
type Shape interface {
    area() float32
    circumference() float32
}
```

I want to create different shapes such as a circle and a rectangle, for the circle I need to know the radius, and for the rectangle the 2 sides. So the code for each is like the following:

```
type DataCircle struct {
     radius float
}

(*DataCircle) area() float32 {
    return 3.14 * DataCircle.radius * DataCircle.radius;
}

(*DataCircle) circumference() float32 {
    return 2 * 3.14 * DataCircle.radius;
}
```

Similarly we have code for a rectangle which implement the interface Shape, with the following struct

```
type DataRectangle struct {
     side1 float
     side2 float
}
```

I want to create many different Rectangles and many different Circles, each one has different radius/sides. In the end I want to put them in a single array and be able to do something like the following

```
for _, shape := range all_shapes_in_array {
    fmt.Printf("%f %f", shape.area(), shape.circumference())
}
```

In a normal object oriented language this is pretty straight forward, but how do I do it in Golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `DataCircle` and `DataRectangle` structs implement the `Shape` interface you will be able to create an array/slice of type `Shape` and iterate through it.

If you already have them implementing `Shape` then all you need to do is this:

```
circle1 := &DataCircle{1}
circle2 := &DataCircle{2}
rec1 := &DataRectangle{1, 1}
rec2 := &DataRectangle{4, 1}

all_shapes_in_array := []Shape{circle1, circle2, rec1, rec2}
for _, shape := range all_shapes_in_array {
    fmt.Printf("%f %f", shape.area(), shape.circumference())
}
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. The problems stemmed from the use of `*DataCircle` in my code, didn't know `*` made a difference.